# Terminology C++ - Members

Tags: c++, class, terminology, member

If someone says "members in the class" are they talking about the data members, or the member functions? I'm a little confused on which one they are talking about.

Comment: Context please. It could be either, but most likely the functions I'd think.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By *"members of a class"* could mean all these:

- data members
- member functions
- nested types

So if you have this class:

```
class A
{
    typedef std::string value_type;  //nested type
    value_type  v;                   //data member
    int         w;                   //data member
    void f();                        //member function
    struct B {};                     //nested type
};
```

then `value_type`, `v`, `w`,`f` and `B` are members of the class `A`.

Comment: Can i consider a friend method as a member of a class ?

Comment: Oh so it's just a general statement. Thanks

Comment: @ScarletAmaranth: No. `friend` is a `friend` not member, just like enemy is an enemy, not friend.

Comment: @ScarletAmaranth: No, a `friend` is something that's by definition *outside* the class, so it's not a member -- it's just a friend.

Comment: @cHao: That is slightly misleading. A `friend` could be *inside* the class as well. There are situations where defining a friend function inside the class itself, provides elegant solutions. A `friend` is by definition a non-member : it could be defined inside the class itself, or outside the class, depending on the actual problem.

Comment: @Nawaz: You could say like `friend void ::doStuff() { ... }`?  Besides the oddness of it (why not make it a `static` member?), i've never seen it done, and really, i don't see how it'd be useful...

Comment: @cHao: Yes, you could say that and `::` is not required. Also, `static` member behaves differently than `friend` function. Think of `friend std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream &, T const &)`

Comment: VS2010 won't even let me do it with the `::`..."IntelliSense: a qualified name is not allowed for a friend declaration that is a function definition".

Comment: That seems to work.  Kinda bizarre, though.  :P  When i see something global, i tend to expect it to be defined outside a class.